# Best way to filtering few columns in dataframe basing on values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**TL:DR**

I need to filter the whole data frame (700k+ rows) and if I found duplicate, or multiple values in `rs` column I need to compare rest columns with other same rows and `if all cols == True` put in `DF1` or `if rest cols =  False`, put all rows with this `rs` to `DF2`. If rs is only one time in wholeDf it should be moved to `DF1`. I write a function but it's take tooo long time.

_

I had a few CSV files looks that:

```
first: 

SNP_name  chrom    pos    rs
A1         2       2121   4234
A2         2       4234   3244
A52        1       5531   2223
A1         3       6666   5324
...

second:
SNP_name  chrom    pos    rs
A1         2       2121   4234
A2         2       4234   3244
A11        5       5555   3213
A11        5       5555   3213
....

third:
SNP_name  chrom    pos    rs
A44        4       3242  e2311
A2         2       4234   3244
A2         2       4234   3244
A55        4       5233   3122
...
```

I need to got all records without repetitions.

So I `concat` all DF to one:

```
wholeDF = pd.concat([df_list[0],df_list[1],df_list[2],df_list[3],df_list[4],df_list[5],df_list[6]])
```

(i know it should be for here, but first functional, then optimize :)

And I got a `WholeDF`:

```
   SNP_name  chrom    pos    rs
    A1         2       2121   4234
    A2         2       4234   3244
    A52        1       5531   2223
    A1         3       6666   5324
    ...
    A1         2       2121   4234
    A2         2       4234   3244
    A11        5       5555   3213
    A11        5       5555   3213
    ....
    A44        4       3242  e2311
    A2         2       4234   3244
    A2         2       4234   3244
    A55        4       5233   3122
    ...
```

And now I pull out an rs values:

```
   values =  wholeDF.rs.value_counts()
```

And I got all rs list with number of occurrences.
example:

```
4234 2
3244 4
2223 1
```

etc.

**What I want to do:**
And I want leave only one record for each `rs` but only if they have same chrom pos and SNP_name.

So in the above example, it should check if `4234` has the same another value in the rest of the rows. If yes - drop rest besides first. If no it should put all rows with this rs to logDF.

result based on above example:

And I tried to do it by for loop (it's more like a pseudocode, I'm writing from memory) :

```
for i in range(len(values)):   
test = wholeDF.where(wholeDF['rs'] == values[i])
for i in range(len(test)):
    if test[0]['SNP_name', 'chrom', 'pos'] == test[i]['SNP_name', 'chrom', 'pos']:
        correct_list.append(WholeDF[i])
    else:
        incorrect_list.append(WholeDF[i])
        print("Error for rs", WholeDf[i].rs)
        return
```

So, in this case, I got a list of correct. Later I can drop duplicates.

But when I run it - WholeDF has 725k rows -  It take few hour to process.

It's possible to do it in simplest way for example in pandas no in for loop?
 Or maybe is abother better idea?

Can someone help me with this task?

Comment: What's wrong with `whole_df.drop_duplicates()`?

Comment: @QuangHoang seems like op wants to move dropped rows to a separate DataFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could work if you really wanted to keep dropped rows:

```
import numpy as np

duplicates = WholeDF.duplicated(subset=['rs', 'chrom', 'pos', 'SNP_name'], keep='first')
logDF = WholeDF.iloc[np.where(duplicates == True)[0]]
WholeDF = WholeDF.drop(WholeDF.index[np.where(duplicates == True)][0])
```

else just use `WholeDF.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)` as @QuangHoang suggested

Comment: Thank U, I will try to do that :)